# How small can the largest of $N$ probabilities be?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose you have $N$ events which are mutually exclusive and whose probabilities add up to one, and suppose that event $1$ has probability $p$ and events $2$ through $N$ have probabilities less than $p$.  Then my question is, how small can $p$ be?

Clearly $p > \frac{1}{N}$, but are there any other constraints?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: @almagest Does this change if no two probabilities are equal?

Comment: No.  For any $\epsilon$, you can have $p(E_1)=\frac 1N +\epsilon$ and $p(E_i)=\alpha=(1-\frac 1N-\epsilon)\big / (N-1)$ for $i>1$.  Easy to see that $\frac 1N +\epsilon +(N-1)\alpha = 1$ which implies $\alpha<\frac 1N$.

Comment: @lulu What if we require that $p(E_n)>p(E_{n+1})$ for all $n$?  Then do we get more constraints?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan No it doesn't change. You can easily take $N$ values differing by an arbitrarily small amount.

Comment: @almagest So you’re saying that the condition $p(E_n) > p(E_{n+1})$ imposes no further constraints on the probability of the first event.  But does it impose any further constraints on the probabilities of the subsequent events?  Can the probability of the second event be arbitrarily low?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Take $p(E_n)=p-n\epsilon$. The sum of the probabilities is 1, so we have $Np-\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)\epsilon=1$ and hence $p=1/N+\frac{(N-1)\epsilon}{2}$ which can be as close as we like to $1/N$.

Comment: law of averages.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Clearly the second and further events have to have probabilities close to $p$.

Comment: @almagest OK, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: $p-{1\over N}\over N-1$ is the average difference of the remaining values from $1\over N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that we must have $p(E_1)>1/N$, because $p(E_i)<p$ for $i>1$ and so $1=\sum p(E_i)<Np$.

It is easy to see that we can get $p$ arbitrarily close to $1/N$. For example, we could take $p(E_i)=p-i\epsilon$, which gives $p=1/N+\frac{(N-1)\epsilon}{2}$ (which is arbitrarily close to $1/N$ for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

Although there are no other conditions on $p$ in the general case, it will obviously have to be bigger than $1/N$ if the values $p(E_i)$ (for $i>1$) are not close to $p$. To take an extreme example, if we took them all to be 0, then we would have to have $p=1$. If we took just one of them to be 0, then we would effectively have the same problem with $N-1$ instead of $N$, so we would need $p>1/(N-1)$.